# Build a transimpedance amplifier that does not invert

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to convert a temperature dependent current from a PT100 into a temperature dependent voltage. I opted for a transimpedance amplifier, but it gives me a negative voltage. How can I construct a circuit that does not give me a negative voltage without using a second opamp?

Comment: This is going to be highly dependent on the details of the current source, I think. If it **must** work into a virtual ground (rather than,  say,  a small resistance that keeps the voltage within some acceptable range) it may not be possible. If you can use a resistance, the solution is trivial, just a non-inverting amplifier with a shunt resistance on the input.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you. I wanted it to work into virtual ground, but I'm not limited to that

Comment: If the temperature dependent current comes from a temperature dependent resistance connected to V+ this is easy. Connect it to V- instead (duly observing polarity). Then the inversion produces a +ve output voltage.

Comment: @Maxim Please provide the current source (sensor) for the input of the transimepedance amp

Comment: Transimpedance amplifiers invert. You are asking for something that probably isn't really what you want. I want a car with only 2 wheels; it's called a bike (for example).